# Sequelize rounding id

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize with SQLite on NodeJS. I have a User table in which I store IDs (16 chars long. `Example: 795051544012783646`). Whenever I query the DB for a specific user, it does something weird with it's ID:

```js
user {
  dataValues: {
    id: 218062175636291600,
    name: 'Raki',
    balance: 0,
    ap: 0,
    objCount: 0
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    id: 218062175636291600,
    name: 'Raki',
    balance: 0,
    ap: 0,
    objCount: 0
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [ 'id', 'name', 'balance', 'ap', 'objCount' ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

The ID should be 218062175636291***586***, but it shows 218062175636291***600***. It's worth noting that the DB itself stores it as it is (it works perfectly).

### What I tried

My User model declares IDs as INTEGERs, so I switched them to BIGINTs. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to get them as strings?

Comment: I did! I figured that since I was not actually going to do anything more than comparing it with other IDs I might as well just use it as a string.